# How to push notifications from sql database to Flutter App

Tags: c#, mysql, flutter, notifications

My problem is that i have only found some tutorials about how to push notifications from firebase database using fcm to devices running an app made with flutter. In my case i have a server with mysql database with a lot of tables. User has the oppurtinity to choose from which table to get notifications from always when something is added to the table. I really dont know how to achieve this. I tried to learn about Fcm but it doesnt seem to be suitable for my purpose. I dont also know how to push notifications directly from sql. Im not using php by the way.
Please dont vote negatively im really sorry im new at this. So i would appreciate your help.
I would be very thankful for your answers.

Comment: Hey. Did you find a solution for this?